# jquery script works correctly only one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a simple script to change the color of everything, based on the div that is hovered over.  It works fine going in one direction (down the line) but if I reverse order and go back, the colors don't work.

The goal is to make everything other than the hovered div turn the same color.  The hovered div should be the default light grey.  Here's two functions of potentially more:

```
$('#red').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).add("#content").removeClass();
    $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("red");
});
$("#blue").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).add("#content").removeClass();
    $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("blue");
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the full thing in action: http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/

Thanks...  (also, I know this JS is super ugly and inefficient.  Beside creating another function to call the redundant parts, not sure how to make it much more concise)

***---***

Answer - I just need to add:

```
$("#content, nav div").removeClass();
```

to every function, otherwise the classes build up and conflict.  Seems kinda silly now... thought I was doing this but definitely not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you are only removing the classes from the mouseover-ed element and `#content` – not from all the other elements, so on those the different color classes keep on “piling up”.

*EDIT: As Steve mentioned in comments, that leads to the last class defined in your stylesheet “winning” (since they all have the same specificity), and that’s why with your original code it worked “down the line”, because the order of hovering the elements matched the order of those classes in your stylesheet.*

You need to remove the classes currently set from *all* elements – you can simply use the same selector for that,

```
$('#red').mouseover(function(){
    $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
    $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("red");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/2/

And then you might as well shorten this to

```
$("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass("red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/4/

And, since you are using the id value as the class name, you might as well shorten the *whole* thing to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav div').mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $("#clear").mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/6/

Comment: +1 Great answer. Can you edit your answer to add that the code in the question works in whatever order the styles are applied, not necessarily "down the line."

Comment: Kudos!  Just about every answer was correct, but this was definitely the most elegant

Comment: @SteveClanton sorry, I don’t get what you mean? I assume by “down the line” OP meant that it only worked when you hover over the divs from top to bottom, but not the other way around. This solution should work in whatever order you hover over the elements, no?

Comment: Yes, yours does. I am saying the reason that it works down the line is that when multiple classes are added to the element, the winning rule is the last rule in the styles. If something has both classes "black yellow," the "background-color: black;" is applied due to specificity.

Comment: @SteveClanton: Ah o.k., got what you mean.

Comment: @SteveClanton: Edited your hint into the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not removing all your previous classes. They are stacking up and only clearing when you hover over each one again. Here is a cleaner way of implementing what you want:

```
$(function(){
    function changeColor(el, className) {
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass()
                              .not(el)
                              .addClass(className);
    }

    $('#red').mouseover(function(){
        changeColor(this, 'red');
    });
    $("#blue").mouseover(function(){
        changeColor(this, 'blue');
    });
    $("#yellow").mouseover(function(){
        changeColor(this, 'yellow');
    });
    $("#black").mouseover(function(){
        changeColor(this, 'black');
    });
    $("#clear").mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").attr('class', '');
    });
});
```

EDIT: Per Steve's comment, the technical reason that you are seeing this problem is because of the order that the classes are listed in your style sheet. Whichever class comes last is the color that will be applied until another class lower in the sheet is applied or the class that is overriding the other classes is removed.

I also updated my answer to use `removeClass()` instead of manually clearing the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. you need to clear your previous classes before you add a class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#red').mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
        $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("red");
    });
    $("#blue").mouseover(function(){
       $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
        $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("blue");
    });
    $("#yellow").mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
        $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("yellow");
    });
    $("#black").mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
        $("#content, nav div").not(this).addClass("black");
    });
    $("#clear").mouseover(function(){
        $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear all classes (`$("#content, nav div").removeClass();`) before you add your class. See this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/1/).

I separated it out into its own function `clearClass()` since it was a common task.

Answer (score 1):

your problem in this line:

```
$(this).add("#content").removeClass();
```

here is a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8bchybrr/5/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#red').mouseover(function(){
            $("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass("red");
        });
        $("#blue").mouseover(function(){
            $("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass("blue");
        });
        $("#yellow").mouseover(function(){
            $("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass("yellow");
        });
        $("#black").mouseover(function(){
            $("#content, nav div").removeClass().not(this).addClass("black");
        });
        $("#clear").mouseover(function(){
            $("#content, nav div").removeClass();
        });
    });
```